# What is the role of attachBaseContext?

Tags: android, android-context

I am confused about why do we use attachBaseContext in android. It would be a great help if someone could explain to me the meaning for the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `attachBaseContext` function of the `ContextWrapper` class is making sure the context is attached only once. `ContextThemeWrapper` applies theme from application or Activity which is defined as `android:theme` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
                                                                                      Since both Application and Service do not need theme, they inherit it directly from `ContextWrapper`. During the activity creation, application and service are initiated, a new `ContextImpl` object is created each time and it implements functions in `Context`.

```
public class ContextWrapper extends Context {
    Context mBase;

    public ContextWrapper(Context base) {
        mBase = base;
    }

    /**
     * Set the base context for this ContextWrapper.  All calls will then be
     * delegated to the base context.  Throws
     * IllegalStateException if a base context has already been set.
     * 
     * @param base The new base context for this wrapper.
     */
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        if (mBase != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Base context already set");
        }
        mBase = base;
    }

}
```

For more details please look [this.](http://ericyang505.github.io/android/Context.html)

Answer (score 11):

**ContextWrapper** class is used to wrap any context(*application context, activity context or base context*) into the original context without disturbing it.
Consider the below example:

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context?) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase))
}
```

Here, `newBase` is the original context which is wrapped by the `CalligraphyContextWrapper` class' `wrap` method which is returning the instance of the `ContextWrapper` class. Now, the modified context is passed to the `ContextWrapper` which is the indirect superclass of *Activity* by calling `super.attachBaseContext()`. And now we can access the context of *Calligraphy dependency* as well as our original context.
Basically, if you want to make use of some other context in the current activity, application or service then do override `attachBaseContext` method.
**PS:**
Calligraphy is just a dependency to get custom fonts [calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)
Check this out to learn more about contexts [dive deep into context](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/mastering-android-context-7055c8478a22)
The official doc about `attachBaseContext` is not thorough but you will get a tentative idea about it.[ContextWrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#attachBaseContext(android.content.Context))