# How to set fontFamily for the entire Xamarin.Android application in a single place?

Tags: xamarin.android, set, font-family

I want to set the `fontFamily` of the Toolbar's texts, Buttons, TextViews and for all the text of the Xamarin.Andrid application in general. How do I do that in a single place? I tried putting the following in the `Base application theme` in `styles.xml` :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    .....
    <item name="fontFamily">@drawable/Exo2_ExtraBold</item>
    .....
</style>
```

But it only changed the `fontFamily` of the `MainActivity`, I guess it's because only that activity has `Theme = "@style/AppTheme"` attribute above it. If I put that attribute above the rest of the activities I guess it will also work, but isn't there an easier way to achieve all the app to have one `fontFamily` setting it in a single place of the application? And also I put the `.otf` file in the `drawables` folder I tried putting it in the `font` folder I created manually but it gave me an error when trying to rebuild the solution. So I'd like to know how can I fix that also, to put the `.oft` in the correct folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to use custom font in android is using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy), for `Xamarin` you can use [CallygraphyXamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CallygraphyXamarin/).

1. Copy your custom font, e.g: `my-custom-font.ttf`, to `fonts` directory, inside `assets` directory.
2. Add [CallygraphyXamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CallygraphyXamarin/) nuget package *`Install-Package CallygraphyXamarin`*
3. Create a class, e.g: `Startup` and add following content to it:

```cs
[Application]
public class Startup : Application
{   
    public Startup(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer) { }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        CalligraphyConfig.InitDefault(
            new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .SetDefaultFontPath("fonts/my-custom-font.ttf")
                .SetFontAttrId(Resource.Attribute.fontPath)
                .Build()
        );      
    }
}
```

4. In your `Activities` add following code and you are good to go.

```cs
protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context context)
{
    base.AttachBaseContext(Calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper.Wrap(context));
}
```

*You can create a base activity to avoid adding above code to each activity.*

**Update:**

In order to change the toolbar's font and if you don't want to add `Textview` as its title, you should add following style to `style.xml`

```xml
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/custom-font.ttf</item>
</style>
```

And apply this style to toolbar like this:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>
```

*[Related github issue](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues/181)*

Comment: In `AttachBaseContext` method `Calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper.Wrap(context)` wasn't recognized as a method so I put `Calligraphy.Xamarin.CalligraphyContextWrapper.Wrap(context)`       
instead. When I ran the application I got the following error at the `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainActivity)` line of the `MainActivity`(which is my main launcher): 
`System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: I posted my `MainActivity.cs` as an answer to my question.

Comment: All my activities except the `MainActivity` have `Toolbar` with title on it. But its `fontFamily` didn't change. What do I do to change it?

Comment: Yes, the new package works. I haven't applied any styles to the `Toolbar` here it is:  
`<Toolbar 
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="@color/appColor" 
  android:title = "Congreso"
  android:titleTextColor = "#FFFFFF"
         android:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_back_button"/>`
neither in `styles.xml`

Comment: I have 3 questions. Does `Startup` class serve only for setting the `fontFamily` for the entire application, or I can put any initialization logic in it? My second question is, if I put `AttachBaseContext` method in a `BaseActivity` , what comment do I put above it, what does it do? My third question , my `MainActivity` inherits from `AppCompatActivity` all the other activities inherit from `Activity`. If I create `BaseActivity` that inherits from `AppCompatActivity` and make `MainActivity` and the rest of the activities inherit `BaseActivity`, will this be a problem?

Comment: 1. [Understanding the Android Application Class](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class). 2. [What is the role of attachBaseContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51759985/3367974). 3. No, there will be no problem (as far as I know), but I think you should use `AppCompatActivity` if you use support libraries, there is no benefit in using `Activity` compare to `AppCompatActivity`, see [Activity, AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity, and ActionBarActivity: When to Use Which?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31297246/3367974).

Answer (score 0):

When we create a new `Activity` , the super class of it is `Activity` in default . So we should change it to `AppCompatActivity` manually . And add the line `Theme = "@style/AppTheme"`

```
using Android.Support.V7.App;
```

```
[Activity(Label = "Activity1", Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]
public class Activity1 : AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: All my activities inherit from `AppCompatActivity` by default. So I have to add `Theme = "@style/AppTheme"` above all the activities? There is no other shorter way?

Comment: Maybe you could create a `BaseActivity` .

Comment: And put the `Theme = "@style/AppTheme"` above it?

Comment: Yes , you can have a try. If it doesn't work , maybe you have to add it on each Activity .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `MainActivity` :

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    Button informationBtn;
    ImageButton congressImageBtn;
    ImageButton exhibitionAreaImageBtn;
    ImageButton facebookImageBtn;
    ImageButton twitterImageBtn;
    ImageButton linkedinImageBtn;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainActivity);

        FindViews();

        BindClickEvents();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to find the views
    /// </summary>
    private void FindViews()
    {
        informationBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.informationBtn);
        congressImageBtn = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.congressImageBtn);
        exhibitionAreaImageBtn = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.exhibitionAreaImageBtn);
        facebookImageBtn = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.facebookImageBtn);
        twitterImageBtn = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.twitterImageBtn);
        linkedinImageBtn = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.linkedinImageBtn);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to bind the click events
    /// </summary>
    private void BindClickEvents()
    {
        informationBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(ContactInformationActivity));
            Finish();
        };

        congressImageBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(CongressActivity));
            Finish();
        };

        exhibitionAreaImageBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(ExhibitionAreaActivity));
            Finish();
        };

        facebookImageBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.facebook.com/");
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };

        twitterImageBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://twitter.com/");
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };

        linkedinImageBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://www.linkedin.com/");
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
    }

    protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context context)
    {
        base.AttachBaseContext(Calligraphy.Xamarin.CalligraphyContextWrapper.Wrap(context));
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's the same. The only difference is that I put `fonts/Exo2_ThinItalic.otf` instead of `fonts/my-custom-font.ttf`. This is the only difference.